# How to take user input in AWS lambda in python

Tags: python, arrays, amazon-web-services, input, aws-lambda

I want to take length of an array 'n' and elements of array 'a[]' as input from user and want to sort that array in AWS lambda function.
But I don't know how to take user input in AWS lambda.

Comment: This is a bit too broad. How is the user providing input? Are they interacting with a website? Are they invoking the lambda from the command line. Lambda functions run in the cloud, so it's not the case that a user can directly interact with the running code.

Answer (score 0):

In your lambda_handler function, that AWS automatically creates for you, you will be getting Event and Context

You want to use the Event to access variables passed to your function.

For example:

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    arrayPassedToFunction = event['yourArray']
```

The Event is a JSON like object hence why you can access each key in the event with ['key']